# Filter UltraGrid column by a different column

Tags: vb.net, filter, ultrawingrid

I have two columns in an `UltraWinGrid`. The first column is rich text formatted text. The second column has the plain text equivalent (RTF removed) of the first column.

I am only showing the first, RTF formatted, column to the user. When the user types in the filter row, I'd like to filter by the second, hidden, column. Is this possible?

Comment: I would be surprised if the filter column didn't let you directly filter against the first column (i.e. it'll automatically remove the RTF for the purpose of filtering). Have you tried this? What happens right now?